# converting sql query to mongodb for below query

Tags: sql, mongodb

Can you please help me in converting the following query into mongo db query

```
Select u.id, sum(t.duration) from user u, time t where u.id=t.usrid and u.role='careManager' groupby u.id
```

Comment: This is a common and simple aggregation with `$match` and `$group` pipeline stages. You can find most common examples in the official documentation [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/)

Comment: Basically though `db.user.aggregate([{ "$match": { "id": usrid, "role": careManager" } }, { "$group": { "_id": "$id", "duration": { "$sum": "$duration" } } }])` is the general translation. But the actual translation depends entirely on your MongoDB data structure and not the "implied" SQL, and you failed to provide a sample document or attempt in your question. Please also see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center.

Comment: Joins are actually facilitated by [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in MongoDB. You should look into that and understand the logic behind them. Again presuming you actually imported into two collections with MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

The mongo shell is a javascript interpreter, and as such doesn't have "join" capability between entities built in. You'll likely need to iterate over each row in the `user` collection, and query the `time` collection per user, using mongo's aggregation or adding up the values yourself depending on a number of things - such as the size of the data set.

Here's one way to do it, which aggregates the time entity, and then looks up each user:

Imagine time has this data:

```
> db.time.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59486011d61e4c5fcd2b0e4f"), "user_id" : "a", "duration" : 200 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5948601dd61e4c5fcd2b0e50"), "user_id" : "b", "duration" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59486025d61e4c5fcd2b0e51"), "user_id" : "a", "duration" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5948602fd61e4c5fcd2b0e52"), "user_id" : "a", "duration" : 110 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59486038d61e4c5fcd2b0e53"), "user_id" : "c", "duration" : 110 }
```

And user has this data:

```
> db.user.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59486073d61e4c5fcd2b0e54"), "role" : "careManager", "user_id" : "a" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5948607ad61e4c5fcd2b0e55"), "role" : "careManager", "user_id" : "b" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59486088d61e4c5fcd2b0e56"), "role" : "notCareManager", "user_id" : "c" }
>
```

Query:

```
db.time.aggregate([{ $group: {"_id" : "$user_id","time": {$sum: "$duration"}} }]).forEach( function(thisTime) { 
   k = db.user.findOne({"user_id":thisTime._id});

   if(k.role == "careManager"){
      print(thisTime._id + ',' + thisTime.time);
   }
})
```

Output:

```
b,100
a,410
```

Comment: `from user u, time t` that's an implicit join between 2 tables.

Comment: Okay. Missed that. There is [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) you know. Which is way more preferable to issuing separate requests. I am also pointing out to the OP that we are making "presumptions" here about how the data is stored in MongoDB. The question therefore is quite unclear and not very useful at this point in time.

Comment: oh nice, i was unaware of $lookup. Is that a relatively new feature? I haven't used mongo in years :D